# cakephpのhasmanyで結合先のカラムが存在しないというエラー事象

Tags: php, cakephp

cakeのアソシエーションを勉強し始めましたが早速つまづきましたので 
ヘルプ求めます！><

以下のようなエラーがでます。（画像も添付します） 
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.email' in 'field list'

[image: エラー画像]

食べログのようなものを練習で作ってます。 
各お店に複数のユーザーがレビューを投稿できるようにする機能です。 
usersテーブルとreviewsテーブルがあり、これらをアソシエーションで連結させたいです。 
（foreignKeyはuser_idです）

usersテーブルにはemail.id共に存在するのですが、 
なぜか上記のようなエラーが表示されてしまいます。

少し調べると下記のような記事を発見しました。 
http://fr-soft.com/cake/?p=32

これと同じような事象でしょうか？ 
（cakeではjoinが実行されない？）

実コードは以下に記載いたします。

getListByShopIdが各ショップごとのレビューを表示させる 
メソッドになります。

＜Review.php＞

```
class Review extends AppModel {
  public $belongTo = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
    ),
    'Shop' => array(
      'className' => 'Shop'
    )
  );

  public function isReview ($shopId, $userId) {
    $review = $this->getData($shopId, $userId);
    return !empty($review) ? true : false;
  }

  public function getData($shopId, $userId) {
    $options = array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'shop_id' => $shopId,
        'user_id' => $userId
      )
    );
    return $this->find('first', $options);
  }

  public function getReviewCnt($userId) {
    $options = array(
      'condition' => array(
        'user_id' => $userId
      )
    );

    return $this->find('count', $options);
  }

  public function getListByShopId($shopId) {
    $options = array(
      'fields' =>
      array('Review.id', 'Review.user_id', 'Review.title', 'Review.body', 'Review.score', 'Review.created', 'User.email', 'User.id'),
      'conditions' => array('Review.shop_id' => $shopId),
      'recursive' => 2
    );
    return $this->find('all', $options);
  }

  public function getScoreAvg($shopId) {
    $options = array(
      'fields' => 'AVG(score) as avg',
      'conditions' => array('shop_id' => $shopId),
      'group' => array('shop_id')
    );

    $data = $this->find('first', $options);
    $score = $scoreAve = 0;
    if (!empty($data[0]['avg'])) {
      $score = round($data[0]['avg']);
      $scoreAve = round($data[0]['avg'], 1);
    }
    return array($score, $scoreAve);
  }
}

?>
```

＜User.php＞

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {

  public $hasMany = array(
    'Review' => array(
      'className' => 'Review'
    )
  );

  public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
      'validEmail' => array(
        'rule' => array('email'),
        'message' => 'メールアドレスを入力してください'
      ),

      'emailExists' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUnique', array('email')),
        'message' => '既に登録済みです'
      )
    ),

    'password' => array(
      'match' => array(
        'rule' => array(
          'confPassword', 'passwordconf' // confPassword(関数名)の呼び出し
        ),
        'message' => 'パスワードが一致しません'
      )
    ),

    'passwordold' => array(
      'match' => array('rule' => array('oldPassword', 'passwordold'),
        'message' => '旧パスワードが一致しません'
      )
    )
  );

  public function confPassword($field,$colum) { // $columはどこから出てきたのか
    if ($field['password'] === $this->data['User'][$colum]) { // $field['password'] = password, $this->data['User'][$colum] = passwordconf
      $this->data['User']['password'] = Authcomponent::password($field['password']);
      return true;
    }
  }

  public function oldPassword($field, $colum) { // $field = usersテーブルのpassword, $colum = passwordold
    $passwordold = Authcomponent::password($field[$colum]); // $passwordoldの暗号化
    $row = $this->findById($this->data['User']['id']);// usersテーブルのidを$rowに格納

    if ($passwordold === $row['User']['password']) { // $passwordoldとusersテーブルのpasswordを照合
      return true;
    }
  }
}

?>
```

＜Shop.php＞

```
<?php

class Shop extends AppModel {
  public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
      'rule' => array('notBlank')
    ),

    'tel' => array(
      'rule' => array('notBlank')
    ),

    'addr' => array(
      'rule' => array('notBlank')
    ),

    'url' => array(
      'rule' => array('url'),
      'message' => '形式が正しくありません'
    )
  );

  public $hasMany = array(
    'Review' => array(
      'className' => 'Review',
      'order' => 'Review.created DESC'
    )
  );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Review.php にて下記のようになっていますが

```
public $belongTo = array(・・・);
```

$belong「s」To ではないでしょうか？